# C3867 non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

Делаю лабораторную по наследованию и полиморфизму, суть такова: к ПК подключен монитор и мышь. Нужно проверить совместимость драйверов. Я создал отдельную Windows Form, которая загружает объекты класса в вектор, который будет перебирать Системные Блоки. Проблема возникла когда я пыталсь тексту `label` присвоить название переменной `string` из объекта.

```
label5->Text = Comps[number_of_SB].getMouseName;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Функция, которая возвращает название мыши:

```
string System_Block::getMouseName()
{
    return Mous.get_name();
}
```

В чём проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
label5->Text = Comps[number_of_SB].getMouseName();
                                              ^^^^
```

Функции без аргументов всё равно вызываются с использованием круглых скобок.